How to predict Future CPU Usage in Time Series reusing your already trained model?
I'm currently working on a time series problem where I need to predict future CPU usage. I have historical data consisting of CPU usage along with features like hour, day of week, and month. However, I'm facing challenges in adapting my model to handle predictions for multiple instances efficiently.
Specifically, I'm looking for insights or approaches on how to build a predictive model for CPU usage in a time series context that can be reused for more than one instance. My dataset includes hourly CPU usage data along with corresponding features such as hour of the day, day of the week, month and lags.
This is my current approach..
def create_features(df):
  """
  Create time series features based on time series index
  """

  df = df.copy()


  df["hour"] = df.index.hour
  df["dayofweek"] = df.index.dayofweek
  df["month"] = df.index.month

  df["lag60"] = df["cpu_usage"].shift(60)
  df["lag10"] = df["cpu_usage"].shift(10)
  df["lag1"] =  df["cpu_usage"].shift(1)
  return df

I have to apply this features to my future 60 minutes predictions. To do this I need to get up to 60 minutos of data before my prediction because I have a lag of 60 minutes.
last_60_min_data = data[["cpu_usage"]].tail(60)
future_index = pd.date_range(start=last_60_min_data.index[-1] + pd.Timedelta(minutes=1), freq="T", periods=60)
future_df = pd.DataFrame(index=future_index)

Now that I have my future data organized with the correct timestamp, I concatenate the 60 minutes prior to my future predictions dataframe.
df_and_future = pd.concat([last_60_min_data, future_df])

Now I apply my features to the entire dataframe
df_and_future = create_features(df_and_future)

If I want to predict the next 60 minutes I only need that timestamp so I filter the df
future_with_features = df_with_features.loc[future_index]

future_with_features




Timestamp
cpu_usage
hour
dayofweek
month
lag60
lag10
lag1




2025-11-25 10:40:00
NaN
10
1
11
42.769924
36.178596
42.334541


2025-11-25 10:41:00
NaN
10
1
11
42.173206
30.630508
NaN


2025-11-25 10:42:00
NaN
10
1
11
41.524266
33.875261
NaN


2025-11-25 10:43:00
NaN
10
1
11
72.094920
2.949912
NaN


2025-11-25 10:44:00
NaN
10
1
11
20.455832
50.194431
NaN


2025-11-25 10:45:00
NaN
10
1
11
11.809337
30.676984
NaN


2025-11-25 10:46:00
NaN
10
1
11
23.748369
35.623488
NaN


2025-11-25 10:47:00
NaN
10
1
11
43.389200
39.436458
NaN


2025-11-25 10:48:00
NaN
10
1
11
34.876873
66.347532
NaN


2025-11-25 10:49:00
NaN
10
1
11
75.034761
42.334541
NaN


2025-11-25 10:50:00
NaN
10
1
11
25.018155
NaN
NaN


2025-11-25 10:51:00
NaN
10
1
11
56.450460
NaN
NaN


2025-11-25 10:52:00
NaN
10
1
11
59.297579
NaN
NaN


2025-11-25 10:53:00
NaN
10
1
11
37.473204
NaN
NaN


2025-11-25 10:54:00
NaN
10
1
11
37.584898
NaN
NaN


2025-11-25 10:55:00
NaN
10
1
11
40.267437
NaN
NaN


2025-11-25 10:56:00
NaN
10
1
11
49.122220
NaN
NaN


2025-11-25 10:57:00
NaN
10
1
11
33.858822
NaN
NaN


2025-11-25 10:58:00
NaN
10
1
11
57.521604
NaN
NaN


2025-11-25 10:59:00
NaN
10
1
11
39.673336
NaN
NaN


2025-11-25 11:00:00
NaN
11
1
11
40.792594
NaN
NaN


2025-11-25 11:01:00
NaN
11
1
11
49.519304
NaN
NaN


2025-11-25 11:02:00
NaN
11
1
11
28.913603
NaN
NaN


2025-11-25 11:03:00
NaN
11
1
11
44.005090
NaN
NaN


2025-11-25 11:04:00
NaN
11
1
11
47.946026
NaN
NaN


2025-11-25 11:05:00
NaN
11
1
11
30.446329
NaN
NaN


2025-11-25 11:06:00
NaN
11
1
11
32.597945
NaN
NaN


2025-11-25 11:07:00
NaN
11
1
11
46.870599
NaN
NaN


2025-11-25 11:08:00
NaN
11
1
11
43.369221
NaN
NaN


2025-11-25 11:09:00
NaN
11
1
11
30.663038
NaN
NaN



What to do next?

Do a forward fill and then use the model to predict?
Is this the best way?
Is their any other alternative so that I can reuse my model for more than 1 prediction into the future?
Is their a way to do this on other libraries more powerful, for example: mlforecast or dart? I'm having trouble replicating this case on those libraries because all the examples train the entire dataset and then predict over a window but they dont reuse the model for more uses...

Thanks for the help!
